# Bind to button function qlik js extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qliksense

I'm developing a simple js extension for Qlik sense and trying to create an extract button just like it provided in [documentation](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/June2020/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/TableAPI/exportData-method.htm)

So I have two options one of them using `angularjs` and the second one jquery + js

First approach:
I've tried with angularjs:

```
html = "<div class='exportArea' style='float:right'><div id='exportText'></div><button ng-click=\"table.exportData({download:true})\">Create Excel file</button></div>" + html;
```

no success

Second Approach:

So I was using **$element.find**

```
$element.find("#exportButton").on("qv-activate", function(){}
```

But later have no idea how to call this export

```
var qTable = qlik.table(this);

var $exportButton = $( document.createElement('button'));
$exportButton.html('Export');
$exportButton.bind('click', function (  ) {
            qTable.exportData({download: true});
        });
$element.append($exportButton);
```

To summarize I need to call code from documentation using tag **id='exportButton'**
inside

```
html = "<div class='exportArea' style='float:right'><div id='exportText'></div><button id='exportButton'>Create Excel file</button></div>" + html;
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

To your first approach:

You will need to define the table in the scope either in the Paint function like this:

```
paint: function ( ) {
    // ...
    if ( !this.$scope.table ) {
        this.$scope.table = qlik.table(this);
    }
}
```

or in the angular controller like this:

```
controller: ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.table = qlik.table(this);
}]
```

To the second approach the $element references the Html Element to append the button to. So either you use this appended Button or you could use a selector function like getElementById (most likely not on the document but rather on the extensionContainer):

```
paint: function ($element, layout) {
    $element.getElementById('exportButton').onlick=()=>{
        qlik.table(this).exportData({download: true});
    }
}
```